# Amazon S3 Access image by url

Tags: amazon-s3

I have uploaded an image to Amazon S3 storage. But how can I access this image by url? I have made the folder and file public but still get AccessDenied error if try to access it by url https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/path/image.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 usually 'just works' - upload the file, set the permissions, and visit the URL. If it doesn't (and their service is functioning) the problem is usually either the wrong URL or the browser cache.

1. Clear your browser cache and reload your pages using ctrl+F5 or ctrl+shift+R
2. Verify the permissions (e.g. use a program (CloudBerry Explorer, Cloudbuddy, etc) or using the AWS Console)
3. Try the alternate form of the path: `https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.ext`
4. Try clicking the link directly from the AWS console; using 'open' the link includes your access keys, and will bypass the ACL settings - don't use that link for anything public, but ensure it works.

I would really suggest using a program (such as those above) and copying and pasting the URL for your tests - it greatly reduces the chance of the URL being incorrect. If the above don't help, you might need to provide a bit more information so that the problem can be diagnosed.

Answer (score -1):

To access private images via URL you must provide [Query-string authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html). Query-string authentication version 4 requires the X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, X-Amz-Signature, X-Amz-Date, X-Amz-SignedHeaders, and X-Amz-Expires parameters.

Comment: Would you be willing to expound on what these parameters need to be?  At this point your answer is a little cryptic.